# Compact way to save a list of subsets

Tags: python, data-structures, subset, memory-efficient

I have an input list L containing about 20-30 elements. I need to keep some of the subsets of L, that satisfy a given condition, so that I can iterate over them later. I can create the list of subsets in the following way:

```
good_subsets = list([s for s in powerset(L) if condition(s)])
```

This works, but might consume a lot of memory. For example, if L has 20 elements, and 50% of them satisfy the condition, then there are about 500,000 subsets.

Is there a more compact way to store the good_subsets in a list? Note that it should be a list and not a generator, since I need to iterate over this list many times later on, and I do not want to generate it each time anew.

Comment: From your description it appears that performance is important. In that case you'll just have to ensure that you have enough [virtual] memory to accommodate the list. If memory really is an issue then perhaps you should use a database

Comment: why use `list([ s for s in ...])`, a list comprehension IS A list

Comment: `good_subsets = { i for i,s in enumerate(powerset(L)) if condition(s) }`, create a set of indices of subsets that satisfy the condition, later test if an index is in the set

Comment: With `n = len(L)` there are `2**n` subsets. Each number in `range(2**n)` can be mapped to a subset by using the binary representation of the number, assigning each bit to an item of `L` with bit 1 meaning that the item is part of the subset, 0 if not. So you finally have to store only the representing numbers.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Indeed, it is much better to store numbers rather than sets.